# What is the right way to cleanly shutdown fabric ca server?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

To start a fabric ca server we use `fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw`

What command or steps need to be followed to shut it down cleanly.

I have read and checked there is no default commands. Refer - https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1963?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but see and comment on https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-4487 to follow the status of adding this support.